# How to mock a class that has many constructor parameters in mockito?

Tags: kotlin, mockito

Let say I have this class A:

```
class A(a: Int, b: String, c: Long, d: Double, ...)
```

Now if I want to test a method that returns a list of objects A:

```
fun test_getListOfObjectsA(){
    val expected = listOf(A(), A(), A())
    whenever(someClass.getListOfObjectsA()).thenReturn(listOf(A(), A(), A()))

    val actual = someClass.getListOfObjectsA()

    assertEquals(expected, actual)
}
```

Here is the problem, this code won't compile because each instance of A() requires a list of argument to be passed in. How can I create a List of A without having to pass all the constructor's arguments every time?

Comment: What is the purpose of that test? In this way you are not testing `getListOfObjectsA()`, you are testing `Mockito`'s mocking behavior.

Comment: Well. I'm only interested in how to mock the class A because later I will test a viewmodel that have some methods that will be called depending  on the List of A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mock the class `A`, you can use `mock<A>()`.

As said in comments, your test isn't testing `getListOfObjectsA()`, it's testing `Mockito`'s mocking behavior.

By the way, the following test passes:

```kotlin
fun test_getListOfObjectsA(){
    val expected = listOf(mock<A>(), mock<A>(), mock<A>())
    whenever(someClass.getListOfObjectsA()).thenReturn(expected)

    val actual = someClass.getListOfObjectsA()

    assertEquals(expected, actual)
}
```

**Important note**

Remember that, since your class is `final`, to successfully mock it, you have 3 choices:

1. make it `open`
2. use the dependency `mockito-inline` to allow the mocking on final classes
3. use the Kotlin `all-open` compiler plugin to make the class and its fields `open` in tests (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to mockito and you saved me a lot of headaches .

Comment: @ToniJoe no problem!